# Getting an error when i use sum

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have datatable which is 'dtTopAll' and it has Event and Waits Columns. All i want is sum Waits column and group by event.

However below code throws an error like 'Waits' column does not belong to table.

```
ultraGrid1.DataSource = dtTopAll;
var dt1 = (from dr1 in dtTopAll.AsEnumerable()
    group dr1 by dr1.Field<string>("Event") into g
    select new
    {
       Event = g.Key,
       Waits = g.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("Waits"))
    }).ToDataTable();

ugWaitEvent.DataSource = dt1;
```

Comment: How do you populate dtTopAll?  It sounds like you don't have a column called "Waits" - maybe you are giving it an alias, or populating the table without naming the columns?

Comment: post your datatable code. your posted code looks ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq queries are case sensitive. Can you try like this way;

```
ultraGrid1.DataSource = dtTopAll;
var dt1 = (from dr1 in dtTopAll.AsEnumerable()
    group dr1 by dr1.Field<string>("Event") into g
    select new
    {
       EVENT= g.Key,
       WAITS= g.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("WAITS"))
    }).ToDataTable();

ugWaitEvent.DataSource = dt1;
```